# Is it possible to change the mysql welcome message?

Tags: mysql

When I connect from the commandline, is it possible to change the welcome message displayed by MySQL?

The current message displays the version, Oracle copyright, etc.

I would also like to display a banner.

Answer (score 8):

To remove welcome message, use `--silent` switch. But it will also make output nontabular (SELECT's output without boundaries) which looks ugly. To bring tabular output back, use `--table` switch.

```
mysql --silent --table -u user_name -p db_name
# or short form
mysql -s -t -u user_name -p db_name
```

To print your own welcome message, create a script, say, `mysql.sh`, and use `echo` to print your banner. Run this script instead of `mysql`.

Example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Welcome to mysql!"
# "$@" will pass script arguments to mysql.
mysql -s -t "$@"
```

Usage:

```
./mysql.sh -u user_name -p db_name
```

You can use bash aliases or functions to substitute `mysql` command with your script, i. e. (assuming you put `mysql.sh` into your `$HOME/bin/`):

```
alias mysql=$HOME/bin/mysql.sh
```

Then `mysql -u user_name -p -db_name` will run your script, that will print your banner and run mysql.

Comment: This works, but sadly also removes the output of number of rows and execution time, e.g. `1 row in set (0.00 sec)` for a select, or `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec) Rows matched: 34  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0` for an update.

Answer (score 5):

Add following in your my.cnf:

```
[mysql]
silent
```

or add --silent to your mysql CLI

and try [logon trigger](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-logon-trigger) to print the banner via  "system echo 'my custom message'". With some more creativity, you can customize per user logon message.

Comment: `silent` will make SELECTs look ugly without boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, you could suppress the welcome message using the `-s` or `--silent` option

```
# mysql -u... -p -s
```

It will immediately present the mysql prompt

```
mysql>
```

Perhaps, you may want to create a shell script with the custom welcome or banner that displays prior to logging into mysql.

If you are a little more daring, you could download the source, locate and change the welcome message, recompile all binaries, and install. If you are that daring, have fun with that one.

Comment: The -s option is smart, but removes the boundaries (signs |, + and -) when executing SELECT-statements. If on *nix; one option is to use an alias and echo a message prior booting mysql.